# A closed set containing all rational points in the square $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

> Assume $A$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing all
> rational points in the square $[0,1]^2$. Prove that $[0,1]^2\subset A$.

My attempt:
Assume $[0,1]^2\not\subset A$. Then there exists a point $(x,y)\in [0,1]^2\setminus A$ that at leasts $x$ or $y$  is irrational (since $A$ contains all rational points in the square $[0,1]^2$).
Because $A$ is closed, $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A$ is open, hence there exists a ball $B((x,y),r)\subset\mathbb{R}^2\setminus A\Rightarrow B((x,y),r)\cap A=\varnothing$.
I don't know how to continue. Could anyone help me?

Comment: You're almost done. Every ball contains rational points.

Comment: You have proved that $B((x,y),r)$ contains no point with rational coordinates. That is a  contradiction.

Comment: @Karl How to prove every ball contains ration points?

Comment: @geetha290krm Could u explain explicitly why that is a contradiction?

Comment: Do you know that there is a rational number between any two different real numbers? And every ball contains a square of the form $[a,b]\times [c,d]$.

Comment: @AlexNguyen you can consider the sequence I defined in my answer and see that $\Vert (x_n, y_n) - (x, y) \Vert \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{10^n},$ where $(x, y)$ is the centre of your ball. Since the latter quantity converges to $0,$ it can be made less than the radius of your ball for suficiently large $n.$

Answer (score 1):

You should be familiar with the fact that $[0, 1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $[0, 1].$ One easy way to see this is to consider $x \in [0, 1]$ and to define $x_n := \frac{\lfloor 10^n x \rfloor}{10^n}$ and observe that $x_n \to x.$ Mutatis mutandis, if $(x, y) \in [0, 1]^2,$ define $(x_n, y_n) := (\frac{\lfloor 10^n x \rfloor}{10^n}, \frac{\lfloor 10^n y\rfloor}{10^n}).$ Then $A \ni (x_n, y_n) \to (x, y),$ so $[0, 1]^2 \subseteq A$ since $A$ is closed. I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier way to go about would be to use the theorem that says that the closure of a set $S$ is the intersection of all the closed sets that contain $S$.